# Highlight first Google result in Safari

Tags: keyboard, safari, google, safari-extensions

In Safari 8, after doing a Google search from the navbar, the focus stays on the navbar instead of focusing on the content like any other webpage.

This prevents the use of Google or DuckDuckGo keyboard shortcuts to open the first result quickly, for instance. You need to click on the page content first, and then you can use the keyboard navigation.

Is there a solution to make it easier? Extension, shortcut, setting, anything?

Comment: This is actually what angers me a lot in Safari 9 as well. I usually have to press the Enter key twice and for some reason after the second Enter press focus goes to the page and we're able to use the page's own shortcuts then. But there has to be a better solution, currently it's looking as a bug or a horrible UX negligence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, try <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> then down-arrow to the result you want and press <kbd>return</kbd>. There will be a tiny arrow to left of the selected link.